# Blue and red cards

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, average, card-games

Imagine that you have 10 blue cards and 10 red cards ordered in random order. And you start revealing them card by card. The first card you draw is, let's say, blue. Also the second card is blue. So you've got a group of 2 of blue cards. Then it continues a group of 3 red cards and so on. And the question is, what is the average number of cards of the same color in a group fon N - red cards and N - blue cards. Thanks for answers.

Comment: similar question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1865/what-is-the-expected-number-of-runs-of-same-color-in-a-standard-deck-of-cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 2n cards, we take any card at random to see if a new sequence has started.

If we choose the first card, with probability 1/(2n), then it can be termed the start of a new sequence.

If we choose any other card, with probability 1 - 1/(2n), there is an n / (2n - 1) chance that the previous card was of the other colour (because n of the remaining 2n-1 cards are that other colour)

prob of selecting run start 
P = 1/(2n) +  (1 - 1/(2n))(n / (2n - 1))
= 1/(2n) +  ((2n - 1) /(2n))(n / (2n - 1)) 
= 1/(2n) + 1/2

if picking a card at random gives us 1/(2n) + 1/2 sampled are the start of a new run, then the average is
2n[1/(2n) + 1/2] = n + 1

answer 
E[no of runs] = n + 1

note:I'm considering a scenario where an infinite number of shuffled decks are sampled at random once only - in that case the observed probability that we see the start of a new run gives us the expected number of runs

If the expected number of runs is n+1, then I figure that the expected length of a run is 2n / (n+1)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried to solve this question. Firstly I realized that $\frac nm$ where n is number of red or blue cards and m is the number of groups of red or blue cards. Then I tried to do the average from all the possible values of m:
$$\frac{n+\frac n2+\frac n3+\frac n4...+\frac nn}{n}$$

And from it follows that the average number of cards in a group should be:
$$1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14...+\frac 1n$$
which is of course the n-th harmonic number.

Comment: Not sure I understand your solution. First, is $n$ the total number of cards? So that, if you have $N$ red and $N$ blue cards, as in the question, then $n=2N$? You seem to say that $1,2,\dots,n$ are "all the possible values of $m,$ but I don't see how $m=1$ is possible, unless all the cards are the same color.

Comment: I´ll try to explain, n is half of the all cards, so if N is the number of all cards then n=N/2, because there is same number of blue cards and red cards. So n is the number of let´s say blue cards. And m=1 is possible because, if you have let´s say 5 blue cards and 5 red cards then there can be a group of 5 blue cards and then follow the remaining 5 red cards. In this case m=1.

Comment: But I don´t know wheter is this a correct answer, because from my answer it would follow that in an infinite number of cards there would be the number of cards in an average group of cards infinite, which doesn´t seem too logical to me. But thanks for question.

Comment: in an infinite chain of 0/1 events, then having reached the start of a chain, its expected length should be 1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + 4/16 + 5 /32 + 6 /64 + .... = 2 - which ties in with my 2n / (n + 1) result, also my result works for n = 1, giving an expected length of '1'